# Prestashop: Product Showing wrong price in Category page but right in the product page

Tags: prestashop-1.5

This type of questions are asked many time. I'm asking again because all the questions and answers are old and I've tried all and none of them are working.
Recently I upgraded my PrestaShop from 1.5.5.0 to 1.5.6.2. Everything seems good since the upgrade but today I came across one problem.

The price of the products are showing ok in the product page but in the category listing or search it shows wrong.

Applied some solutions but non of them working.
1. Deactivated/activated the manufacturer block
2. Used default theme but same result.
3. Cleared the smarty cache.
4. Checked the default language  and currency.
5. Checked with Logging out/in. 
Can anybody help me by suggesting why it's not showing the correct price ? 
You can simply view the problem here 
First go here  and view the price then click on the product and view the price. Please help.

Some Screen Shots:-
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have any combinations what could affect the price? are you sure you are displaying the SAME price on both of the pages ( places ). There are numerous ways which all have different variables like tax included, tax excluded, discount price and so no.

Comment: I've a lot of combinations but they were working well before. I've a discount of 10% discount on a category but that is not related with products that are showing the differed price.

Comment: is the change same on all products ? Amount that has been added ?

Comment: No not all product but some of them. I couldn't get any logic why this is showing this type of thing. Products having combinations are showing this wrong price but strange thing is not all products are showing wrong price.

Comment: Try to create some blank product examples. And see if the price does the same thing on them. We need to understand if this error might come from some function or is prestashop adding something to those products. Some cart rule or tax rule or something like that.

Comment: Ok let me try. Thank You

Comment: I've created new product and tested but it shows everything correctly.Can't find a logic why is it happening.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47309/discussion-between-jnana-and-user2831723)

Comment: I got a solution to it but not really a solution but the issue or bug. When I edit the product combinations, change the bottom attribute which has price impact and alter them with having attributes with no price impact then it shows the correct price in the product list. In other words keeping one attribute at bottom of the combination generator with no price impacts makes the correction . But why is it happening like this and to some old product. Can anyone shed some light on it ?

Comment: Probably some combination is used as a default one. Which has impact on the price. Check it :)

Comment: May be but I'm not sure.

Comment: Enabling Layered navigation Block causes this problem. After disabling  it works perfectly.

Comment: Can you give a bit longer explanation then that? Do it as an answer, i'm happy to give you vote up for that then :)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure it this help with above issue, but when some of product prices were zero, those queries solved it. They fixed the issue when prices were 0 in one of the shops in multistore configuration (Prestashop 1.6.0.6):

```
UPDATE ps_product SET cache_default_attribute = 0;
UPDATE ps_product_shop SET cache_default_attribute = 0;
```

Comment: Issue solved after removing special page from the front office. I remember I've tried his method but didn't work.

Comment: If upgrade from 1.4 to 1.6 this problem will appear for some reason and above solution will fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

After a long time as I didn't get any solution and from my own experiments I found a solution so I'm posting that as an answer to my own question. 
I got to know from different suggestion( [like this](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/307582-product-showing-wrong-price-in-category-page-but-right-in-the-product-page/page-2#entry1560675)) that internal modules sometimes cache some data which may be cleared by clearing the cache but one Idea came to my mind that some different module mat be keeping some impact on them. So I tried with different modules where price impact is an important aspect so I just disabled the "Layered Block navigation" Module as the price is also in filtration method used here. After disabling it works better and problem got solved.

**I have created an issue and finally prestashop team solved here is the [link](http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/PSCFV-11694) solution.**  They made some modifications in the blocklayered.php

Answer (score 0):

PS 1.6.1.5, after some combinations were deleted cache_default_attribute was filled with obsolete reference, once following (as stated in one of previous posts above) was executed problem went away:

```
UPDATE ps_product SET cache_default_attribute = 0;
UPDATE ps_product_shop SET cache_default_attribute = 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you using blocklayered module? This module get the data by Db object instead of getting the price throught Product or Product Controller.